# Is "bites the heads off crocodiles" correct or do we need "of" ("bites the heads off of crocodiles")?

Tags: prepositions

I saw this phrase today in a [meme](https://ifunny.co/picture/2KDpPVfd9?s=cl):

> Visit Australia - Where there's stuff that bites the heads off crocodiles.

Because of the way my natural language works, makes more sense to me if there was an *of* after the *off*, making it

> Visit Australia - Where there's stuff that bites the heads off **of** crocodiles.

But I agree that the phrase would be horrible that way.

Is the first phrase ok or is there a kind of construct that must be used in that case?

Comment: This was answered over at ELU: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/619/how-can-i-explain-to-people-that-the-phrase-off-of-is-grammatically-incorrect

Comment: Memes aren't known for correct spelling or grammar.

Comment: "off of" is generally viewed as non-standard.  Many people do use "off of", but this is informal/colloquial English.  I wouldn't use it in formal English writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that "off" vs "off of" is largely a matter of preference and there is some debate about it. For example:

- [Off Of – Usage & Meaning](https://grammarist.com/usage/off-of/)
- [Is “off of” so awful?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/12/is-off-of-so-awful.html)

It seems that "off of" is often considered either redundant or incorrect depending on who you ask. It also appears to be more common in American English as opposed to British English.
Either way, you're unlikely to be criticised for either so feel free to use whichever you want in everyday usage.